# Generalize the Pythagorean theorem to sub-spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I encountered this problem several months ago and was always trying for a solution. Today I  got the answer and wanted to write it down here. Let k < n are two positive integers. The problem is:

> Given n real numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$, if and only if $a_i\in[0,1], i=1,2,\dots, n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=k$, then there is a $n\times k$ real matrix $q=\{q_{ij}\}$ such that
>
> 1. $q^tq=I$, i.e. Column vectors are orthonormal;
> 2. $\sum_{j=1}^k q_{ij}^2=a_i, i=1,2,\dots, n$, i.e. Lengths of row vectors are specified.

First I reformulated the problem as:

> Given n real numbers $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_n$, if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^n\cos^2\alpha_i=k$, then there is a k-dimensional subspace S of $R^n$, such that the angle $\angle(S,e_i)=\alpha_i, i=1,2,\dots,n$. Where $e_1, e_2, \dots, e_n$ are the n coordinate vectors.

The angle between a subspace S and a vector $v$ is defined to be the angle between $v$ and $P(v)$, where $P(v)$ is the orthogonal projection of v in S.

[image: Orthogonal projection to s]

Note that when k=1 this is just the Pythagorean theorem. I will show in the answer that the two problems are equivalent.

Comment: I don't get how to understand the "if and only if" parts of the statement.

Comment: Example: Given n numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$, if and only if $\sum a_i^2 = 1$, there is a unit vector v, whose components are $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$. Basically this post tries to solve the following problem: Given n angles, how to construct a k-dimensional subspace S, such that the angles between S and the coordinate vectors, are the specified values.

Comment: That "if and only if" still does not seem to make sense there. That sentence is meant to go between the two statements it refers to.

Comment: Let me change my statement: The sufficient and necessary condition for n numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ to be the components of a unit vector is: $\sum a_i^2=1$

Answer (score 0):

First let me show that the two problems are equivalent. A $n\times k$ matrix $q=\{q_{ij}\}$ with orthonormal column vectors $(q_1, q_2, \dots, q_k)$ satisfies $q^tq=I$, and it determines a subspace of $R^n$:
$$S=\operatorname{span}\{q_1, q_2, \dots, q_k\}$$
Let $a_i=\sum_{j=1}^kq_{ij}^2$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$, $a_i$ is just the diagonal elements of the matrix $P=qq^t$. Note that P is nothing but the orthogonal projection operator of S, since $P^2=P, P^t=P,tr(P)=k$ and $\forall w, Pw=q(q^tw)=(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k)(q^tw)$ is a linear combination of the k column vectors, so $Pw\in S$.
So we have $$a_i=P_{ii}=e_i^tPe_i=\langle e_i, Pe_i\rangle=|e_i||Pe_i|\cos\angle(e_i,Pe_i)$$
$$=\cos^2\angle(e_i,Pe_i)=\cos^2\angle(e_i,S)$$

So giving the n numbers $\{a_i\}$ is equivalent to giving the n angles between the subspace S and the n coordinate vectors.
On the other side, given a k-dimensional subspace S, we can choose an arbitary orthonormal basis $\{q_1, q_2, \dots, q_k\}$ of S, to build the matrix $q=(q_1, q_2, \dots, q_k)$, then $P=qq^t$ being the orthogonal projector, is determined, independent of the choices of basis.

---

Back to the original problem. First let's prove the following

> Lemma 1: Given two vectors $v, w$ with $\cos^2\angle(v,S)=m$ and $\cos^2\angle(w,S)=M$, where $m \le M$. Then $\forall b \in [m, M]$, there is a vector $u$ which is a linear combination of $v,w$, such that $\cos^2\angle(u,S)=b$.

Proof of Lemma 1: the function $\cos^2\angle(\cos{t}\cdot v + \sin{t}\cdot w,S)$ is continuous on t. The conclusion follows from the Intermediate value theorem. Q.E.D.

To compute the matrix $q$ from $\{a_i\}$, we take an iteration of $n$ steps.

> Initialization:
>
> 1. $q \leftarrow (e_1, e_2, \dots, e_k), S \leftarrow \operatorname{span}(q)$
> 2. $v \leftarrow e_n, w \leftarrow e_1, m \leftarrow 0=\cos^2\angle(v,S), M \leftarrow 1=\cos^2\angle(w,S)$
> 3. $A \leftarrow \{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}, B \leftarrow \{1,\dots,1,0,\dots,0\}, A \subset [m, M]$

S is the subspace spanned by the column vectors of q. A is the set of the n given numbers, satisfying $a_i \in [0,1], i=1,2,\dots, n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = k$. B is the set of the squares of lengths of each row of q. That is, A contains the desired values and B contains the current values. Our iteration updates an element of B each step, to match an element in A. So that after n steps, B will be identical with A.

> In each step:
>
> 1. Choose an element $a$ from A who's closest to the boundary of $[m, M]$. That is, $a$ minimize $\{min(|a-m|,|a-M|) | a \in A\}$. Suppose $a$ is closer to $M=b_i=\cos^2\angle(e_i,S)$ than to $m=b_j=\cos^2\angle(e_j,S)$.
> 2. From Lemma 1, we can choose a new basis $\{u_i, u_j\}$ for the plane $e_i\wedge e_j$, such that $\cos^2\angle(u_i,S)=a$, re-express q with respect to this new basis. That is: $q_{ix} \leftarrow \langle u_i, q_x\rangle, q_{jx} \leftarrow \langle u_j, q_x\rangle, x = 1,2,\dots, k$. 
>    Update $B$ accordingly: $b_i \leftarrow a, b_j \leftarrow (b_i+b_j-a)$
> 3. $A \leftarrow A-\{a\}, B \leftarrow B-\{M\}$ or $B \leftarrow B-\{m\}$, according to who's closer to $a$.
> 4. $m \leftarrow min\{B\}, M \leftarrow max\{B\}$

Since $a$ is chosen to be the one closest to $M$( or $m$), the above steps don't violate the assumption that $A \subset [m, M]$. Then we can repeat the above steps till A gets empty. At the end, $q$ will be the desire matrix. Q.E.D.

The proof also gives the algorithm to really compute the result matrix $q$.
I pasted the JavaScript code implementing the algorithm [here](http://xipanxiao.wordpress.com/2013/09/20/the-javascript-code-to-solve-an-algebra-problem/).